# Problem to integrate PayU SDK in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to integrate into a PayU application for Android, I downloaded the files and integrate it into a new module. When you finish compiling, throw this error.

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Update Build Tools version and sync project
Open File

Failed to resolve: phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:0.1.3
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog

I go to the new module and change it for implementation and Version 28.0.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0.1"
}

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:7.2.5'
implementation 'com.payu.india:payu-sdk:4.4.5'
implementation 'com.payu.samsungpay:samsungpay:1.0'
implementation 'com.payu.magicretry:magicretry:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.payu.phonepe:phonepe-intent:1.0.0'
```

and a new problem appears :

> Failed to resolve: phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:0.1.3
>   
> Open File
>   
> Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: for the simple payu functionality, you only need the first 2 dependencies. Phonepe is not necessary

Comment: Also there is a difference between warning and error. Configuration compile is obsolete is warning message not error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to add the repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error Could not GET 'https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/com/braintreepayments/card-form/maven-metadata.xml'

Comment: please help me, i have used  url "https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK" but problem exist